# how to send one udp packet multiple time in scapy ?

Tags: udp, scapy

How to send one udp packet multiple time in scapy ? I need to send,an valid udp packet more than one times. Is there any specific method or function in scapy ?

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```
sendp(p, iface=eth0, inter=1 , count=x )
```

Where `p` is your packet or a list of packets and `count` is the number of times to repeat the send operation.

Also check the corresponding documentation [scapy.sendrecv Namespace Reference](http://fossies.org/dox/scapy-2.3.1/namespacescapy_1_1sendrecv.html).

Answer (score 2):

create ip packet

```
i=IP()
i.dst="destination ip "
```

create udp packet

```
u=UDP()
u.dport="destination port"
```

now send

```
while(1)
{
send(i/u)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With this line, your packet will be send continuously, on a loop :

`send(packet, loop=1)`

Comment: I noticed that when loop=2 is specified it works as well. What is the difference between `loop=1` and `loop=2`?

Comment: *loop=2* means you sent two packets at the same time, in a loop.

Answer (score -1):

You can do in a normal loop. Created the valid UDP packet and then put the sending function in a simple loop as follows:

```
for packet in range(No. of time you want to send the packet):
      send(Your UDP packet)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This is very slow; use sendp() (as suggested above) to get a reasonable rate.

Comment: @Symmetric How can I send packet one by one and in a fast speed using scapy? I need to modify every packet and send it out, problem is that send(packet) takes a long time. Do you know that there is a solution?