# What is the best way to fork scapy in order to duplicate packets

Tags: python, udp, fork, scapy, packets

I have a pretty simple script which supposed to duplicate packets using scapy:

```
from scapy.all import *
import pprint

ips = [
"192.168.0.1",
"192.168.0.2",
"192.168.0.3",
"192.168.0.4",
"192.168.0.5",
"192.168.0.6",
"192.168.0.7"
]

def dup_pkt(pkt):
        pprint.pprint(pkt)
        if pkt[IP].dst == "10.0.0.1":
                for ip in ips:
                        pkt2 = copy.deepcopy(pkt)
                        pkt2[IP].dst = ip
                        print "Packet1:",pkt[IP].dst,"Packet2:",pkt2[IP].dst
                        send(pkt2)

pkts = sniff(prn=dup_pkt, filter="port 53", store=0, count=2)
```

Instead of the for loop, I wish to send it to the multiple destination all at once. I thought about forking processes which each one will send the packets but it still leaves me with the for loop.

Also - send() is very slow, but sendp() does not fit as I have different destinations.

I've read this one: [how to send one udp packet multiple time in scapy ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247806/how-to-send-one-udp-packet-multiple-time-in-scapy) but there is no answer there.

How can I send multiple packets at once?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `send()` function can receive a list of packets to send:

```
def dup_pkt(pkt):
    pprint.pprint(pkt)
    if pkt[IP].dst == '10.0.0.1':
        pkts = []
        for ip in ips:
            pkt2 = pkt.copy() # use the copy method rather than copy.deepcopy
            pkt2[IP].dst = ip
            pkts.append(pkt2)
            print "Packet1: ", pkt[IP].dst, " Packet2: ", pkt2[IP].dst
        send(pkts) # send all packets at once
```

Comment: Working great. Thanks!